# How to change Display Name of Safari Extension for iOS devices?

Tags: xcode, app-store, safari-extension, ios15

Can you please help me change the *Display Name* of the Safari Extensions(**iOS v15**) for the iPhone/iPad?

I did try (in **Xcode**) all combinations of updating *Build* and *Bundle Id*s and display names, but nothing worked.  I tried updating the *CBBundleDisplayName* property in the project file and also in *plist* file, but didn't make any difference.

My app/extension ID is: "*ABC.MNO.XYZ*", and accordingly, there are four targets generated in Xcode, mainly App, Test, UITest, Extension.

The last target (Extension) one is already set to "*ABC MNO XYZ Extension*" by default, and there I tried to change its *Display Name* **without suffix of *Extension***, but nothing worked, causing either build issues or no change in the app.

In sum, the app name and extension name, both in **Settings > Safari > Extensions** and also in the **Safari Browser Extension's popup menu**, should be set to "**ABC MNO**".

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the "`name`" attribute in the `manifest.json` file, within the **Targets** projects, that(last folder) ends with the suffix "*Extension*", like "*ProjectName Extension*".

Then, remove the existing (installed) extension on the device, and rebuild the project, to see the new custom name.